# Why modal does not show the value in HTML?

Tags: html, angularjs, modal-dialog

Hi I have created this plunker and I am trying to print out the value in function `usman`in HTML. But it does not show any guesses whats missing ?

```
[My plunker][1]
```

I have a function in `Dashboardcontroller` from where I am getting values and after the values i AM passing these value to modal.

```
$scope.view_product = function (id) {
        console.log(id);
        $http.get('http:',
                {headers:
                            {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                                'Authorization': $rootScope.keyword_auth_token}
                })
                .success(function (data) {
                    $scope.data_vp = data;
                    $scope.price = data.product_variants[0].price;
                    $scope.name = data.name;
                    $scope.variants = data.product_variant_options;
                    $scope.language_id = data.language_id;
                    console.log($scope.data_vp);
                    if ($scope.data_vp)
                    {
                        ctrl.open();
                    }
                })
                .error(function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                });
    };
```

and I am using the values in html

```
`<div class="modal-header">
    <h3 class="modal-title" id="modal-title">Update Product</h3>
</div>
<div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 modal-body" id="modal-body" ng-controller="DashboardController">
    <form class="col-md-8 col-xs-12 col-sm-12" ng-submit="add_product()" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 form-group">
            <label for="language_id">Select language:</label>
            <select name="language_id" class="register mg-bt-15 wid-100-p" required>
                <option ng-model="language_id" value="1">English</option>
                <option ng-model="language_id" value="2">Arabic</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <p> This is testing {{abc}}</p>
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 form-group">
            <label for="item_name">Item Name:</label>
            <input class="form-control" ng-model="name" id="name" type="text" required>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 form-group">
            <label for="item_price">Item Price:</label>
            <input class="form-control" ng-model="price" id="item_price" type="text" required>
        </div>
        <div data-ng-repeat="variant in variants" class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 form-group">
            <label for="text">{{variant.variant_name}}:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="variant.variant_value">
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 form-group">
            <hr/>
            <div class="btn btn-primary" ngf-select="uploadFiles($files)" multiple 
                 accept="image/*">Select Files</div>
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="f in files" style="font:smaller">
                    {{f.name}}
                </li>
            </ul>

            <ul id="product_uplaoded_images">
                <li ng-repeat="img in path" style="font:smaller">
                    <img ng-src="http://35.160.167.13/online-malls/common/upload/productpic/{{img}}" alt="upload_image">
                    <span class="badge" ng-click="remove_upload_img($index)"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></span>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <span class="progress" ng-show="progress >= 0">
                <div style="width:{{progress}}%" ng-bind="progress + '%'"></div>
            </span>
            {{errorMsg}}
            <hr/>
        </div>

        <div class="aa-single-submit form-group">
            <input class="btn btn-success mg-10" type="submit" value="Update Product" name="submit">                
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="ctrl.ok()">OK</button>
    <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button" ng-click="ctrl.cancel()">Cancel</button>
</div>`
```

and this is also the remaining part of `controller`

```
    ctrl.open = function (size, parentSelector) {

        var parentElem = parentSelector ?
                angular.element($document[0].querySelector('.modal-demo ' + parentSelector)) : undefined;
        var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
            animation: ctrl.animationsEnabled,
            ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-title',
            ariaDescribedBy: 'modal-body',
            templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
            controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
            controllerAs: 'ctrl',
            size: size,
            appendTo: parentElem

        });

        modalInstance.result.then(function () {

        }, function () {
            $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
        });


    };
    ctrl.toggleAnimation = function () {
        ctrl.animationsEnabled = !ctrl.animationsEnabled;
    };
angular.module('mainControllers').controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function ($scope, $uibModalInstance) {
var ctrl = this;

ctrl.ok = function () {
    $uibModalInstance.close();
};

ctrl.cancel = function () {
    $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
};
```

});
     can you please tell me how can I solve it ?

Comment: Please add a [mcve]

Comment: What are you trying to print? The only `log()` call is when the model gets dismissed...

Comment: in example.js you can see  $scope.abc = "DONE"; I want to print I am printing Done

Comment: @alldani sorry to say but I think the plunker is enough for the minimal, complete and verifiable example

Comment: It needs to be on Stack Overflow. Some users can't open new links easily.

Answer (score 0):

You are using two controllers and the **ModalInstanceController** is the one responsible for the modal value, where as you had your value in the **ModalDemoCtrl** controller.

Here it is your plunker is working. [**Plunk**](https://plnkr.co/edit/KiL42J?p=preview)

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', 
function ($scope,$uibModalInstance) {
  var ctrl = this;
  $scope.abc="DONE";//// modified here
  ctrl.ok = function () {
    $uibModalInstance.close();
  };

  ctrl.cancel = function () {
    $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  };
});
```

Alternative option is to have the **ModalDemoCtrl** as the base controller as below

```
ctrl.open = function (size, parentSelector) {
    var parentElem = parentSelector ? 
      angular.element($document[0].querySelector('.modal-demo ' + parentSelector)) : undefined;
    var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
      animation: ctrl.animationsEnabled,
      ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-title',
      ariaDescribedBy: 'modal-body',
      templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
      controller: 'ModalDemoCtrl',

      size: size,
      appendTo: parentElem

    });
```

and have your scope element outside the **usman()** method as in this demo **[Plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/7mZR0J?p=preview)**

Comment: sir what if I have a function which is not in ModalDemoctrl and I am getting values from that function?

Comment: there are various options ! what exactly is ur  requirement

Comment: you did a copy paste of your plunker??

Comment: see the viewproduct function

Comment: clearly tell me what is that you are facing? read your updated post once. and with two three lines of explanation what you can understand?